EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES not working
I have created a custom module and registered a route like this.
EVENT::on(
            UrlManager::class,
            UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES,
            function (RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
                // Create mailchimp subscription
                $event->rules['api/newsletter/subscribe'] = 'commerce-extension/mailchimp/subscribe';
            }
        );

However when I use this in my form it always returns a 404.
          <form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" novalidate>
            {{ csrfInput() }}
            {{ actionInput('/api/newsletter/subscribe') }}
            <input type="email" name="email">
            <button type="submit">Inschrijven</button>
          </form>

Using an actionInput that links directly to the controller works without issues.
{{ actionInput('/commerce-extension/mailchimp/subscribe') }}
Am I doing something wrong?
EDIT: I just noticed that the newly registered URL works when posting to it with fetch in javascript. Maybe there is something wrong with the actionInput?

I believe you're missing referencing correctly the namespace as in namespace/controller/action
Check if 'commerce-extension' is the proper namespace...
I'd search within vendor folder for this MailchimpController class and double check

It is correct. But let's say it isn't. Shouldn't using /commerce-extension/mailchimp/subscribe as the direct actionInput in the form fail then? This works. Which leads me to believe that it is something with the routing rather than the namespace.
